# Delete resources that are not there iphone

Tags: iphone, resources

I'm trying to import a Default.png in my application but it's not getting imported and showing me a message that it's already there whereas there's no Default.png already present in my resources.

This might be because I by mistake had assigned my current working app Id and provisioning profile to an another application too since when it had started showing me that app's Default.png before loading my application. To remove that I had done restarting, cleaning and managed to remove the appearence of that Default.png, but because of this message I am feeling that it's still there and I want to remove it or the Default.png that's not there in my resources but is depicted to be there in my resources.

I have double-checked and there is no Default.png in my applications' resources.

Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete something from the Xcode project, it will ask you if also you want to delete it from disk. You might have chosen to delete a reference only.

So herhaps it's still in the project folder on your harddrive. Check that and remove any Default.png files before adding the new one in Xcode.